# Reading from & updating a multi-select/pick list in Dynamics 2011 via SOAP API interface

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I am connecting to a 2011 IFD Dynamics deployment and having no issues (finally) reading & writing data where a field is a string or boolean.

I can't seem to find any examples of how to read/write data to a multi-select (pick list) field.

My XML to update a bool is:

```
<b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
    <c:key>py3_treatschildren</c:key>
    <c:value i:type="d:boolean" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">true</c:value>
</b:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
```

Can someone advise the correct XML syntax to update / replace selected values in a pick list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PickList would be of the type "OptionSet", the SOAP request would be (e.g. For Contact - option set - gendercode):

```xml
 <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
     <b:key>gendercode</b:key>
     <b:value i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
         <a:Value>1</a:Value>
     </b:value>
 </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
```

Comment: Thank you - would the same apply for setting multiple values where allowed? The example I'm working on is a multiple select allowing users to choose the languages they speak

Comment: CRM natively has no support from multi-select controls, so I am assuming you have customized it, in which case, you cannot "update multiple values", how have you customized it? How do you store all the selected "languages" ?

Comment: Ah this is probably why I've not found a solution from searching - didn't realise there isn't an option for multi-select controls.